# Toggle background-color app by clicking on a button in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, button, toggle, styled-components

I would like to have a button, that will change background color of my app. I know how to do onClick, that will change my color once, but I would prefere to have toggle button instead.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState("#673ab7");

  const setStyle = (backgroundColor) => {
    setBackgroundColor(!backgroundColor);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Header setStyle={setStyle} backgroundColor={backgroundColor} />
      <Weather backgroundColor={backgroundColor} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Component with button

```
export const Header = ({ setStyle, backgroundColor }) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <HeaderApp>
        <HeaderTitle>Your Weather App</HeaderTitle>
        <ButtonForm onClick={() => setStyle("#fff")}>
          {backgroundColor === "#673ab7"
            ? "Change Background"
            : "Previous Background"}
        </ButtonForm>
      </HeaderApp>
    </header>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you will need to initialize the state of the background :

```
const Color_One = "#000";
const Color_Two = "#fff";
const [Background, setBackground] = useState(Color_One);
```

and then you need to create a function that will handle the click event :

```
const onChangeBackground = e => {

   e.preventDefault();

   if(Background === Color_One){

      setBackground(Color_Two);
   }
   else {

      setBackground(Color_One);
   }
}
```

And finally in your Button Form  Component :

```
   <ButtonForm onClick={onChangeBackground}>
      // some code
    </ButtonForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use code that @Jesse Locas provided or your code also work fine with some changes,

```
const setStyle = (newColor) => {
    setBackgroundColor(newColor);
};
```

change your parameter backgroundColor to newColor so your state backgroundColor don't conflict while setting up new background color and there is no need of `!`
.

I hope this will help you.

Thank You.